# 閲覧数は同じ人だと伸びる事はない？

Tags: サポート

プロフィール閲覧数や、質問の閲覧数（影響力）がありますが、同じ人が何回見ても伸びる事はありませんか？

Comment: どういう方法で、閲覧数を集計しているのでしょうか? ログインとクッキー? もし、クッキーだと、ログインせずに閲覧する事で、簡単に増やすことできますね。(だから、Yahooの意識調査とかはいくらでも操作可能)

Comment: 自分で試してみても増える事はないのでたぶんログインじゃないかなと思うのですが、定期的に初期化されたりすることもあるのかなと思ったりしました。

Comment: 投票をする人数の意識調査をするみたいなことを書いたのですが、投票の大切さについての閲覧回数が現在５００近くあるので、少なくとも５００人の方はご覧になっているのかなと考えたいと思っています。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

非公式の第三者ユーザーによる推測は Meta Stack Exchange で[行われています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/341401)。この投稿によると2011年時点では、ユーザーID または IP ごとに、一定の時間間隔を持って行われたアクセスを1ヒットに数えていると推測されています。

Comment: これだと純粋に５００名以上が投票に関心を持ってらっしゃるとは思えないわけですね。ありがとうございます。